There is $M$ such that $m^*(E \backslash [-M,M]) < \epsilon $ for $m^* = $ Lebesgue outer measure
Given that for a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}, and $ $m^*(E)< \infty$ (outer measure), I want to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have an interval $[-M,M]$ such that
$$ m^*(E \backslash [-M,M]) < \epsilon $$
What I have tried is using the continuity theorem for measurable sets and write $E= \cup E \cap [-n,n]$, but $E$ is not measurable so this method will not work.
I do not have any idea on approaching questions like this. Any ideas/hints will be highly appreciated.

This question is similar to: Prove that for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $M>0$ such that $m^* (E \setminus [-M,M]) < \varepsilon$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

By definition of the Lesbesgue outer measure, there exists $\{A_k\}_{k\in\mathbb N}$ a countable disjoint sequence of open intervals such that it covers $E$ and exceeds the (outer) measure of $E$ by at most $\epsilon$ (just so that the cover has finite measure):
$$m^*\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 0} A_n\right)\leq m^*(E)+\epsilon, \,\, E\subseteq \bigcup_{n\geq 0} A_n$$
Take $N\in\mathbb N$ to be such that:
$$m^*\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 0} A_n\right)\leq m^*\left(\bigcup_{n= 0}^N A_n\right)+\epsilon$$
Now the set on the RHS is a bounded open set (finite union of open intervals) and thus we can contain it inside a symmetric open interval $I$. Now we have:
$$m^*(E\backslash I)\leq m^*\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 0}A_n\backslash I\right)\leq m^*\left(\bigcup_{n>N}A_n\right)\leq \epsilon$$

One detail: from $m^\left(\bigcup_{n\geq 0} A_n\right)\leq m^\left(\bigcup_{n= 0}^N A_n\right)+\epsilon$ it does not quite follow that $m^*\left(\bigcup_{n>N}A_n\right)\leq \epsilon$, right?

In this case it does, the $A_n$s are proper open intervals, and thus the outer measure reduces to the typical Lebesgue measure, and thus we have additivity.
